# Python regular expression for String starting with tr(" and ending with ")

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to write a regular expression in Python that will give me all strings enclosed within tr("   ").

For example,

```
str = 'According to some, dreams express tr("profound aspects of personality")' and 'tr("Foulkes 184"), though others disagree.'
```

So I want string "profound aspects of personality" and "Foulkes 184"

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 4):

No look-behind/ahead needed, a simple group in [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will suffice:

```
> s = 'According to some, dreams express tr("profound aspects of personality") "and" tr("Foulkes 184"), though others disagree.'
> re.findall(r'tr\("(.*?)"\)', s)
['profound aspects of personality', 'Foulkes 184']
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xgG9AO/5

From the `findall` docs:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups.